# ng-click in ng-repeat with url redirect

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to redirect the page using ng-click which is avail in ng-repeat.

1. ng-repeat code:

   ```
               <tr ng-repeat="students in studlist" ng-click="gotoProfile(1)">
                   <td width="12%" class="student-list-pic-column"><img src="<?=base_url()."data/student-img/{{ students.photo }}";?>"></td>
                   <td width="50%" class="custom-table-border-body text-left">{{ students.studname }}</td>
                   <td width="38%">{{ students.bid }}</td>
               </tr>
               <tr ng-show="!studlist.length">
                   <td colspan="3" class="custom-table-border-body text-center">
                       Search student name ...
                   </td>
               </tr>
   ```

Here in ng-click="gotoProfile(1)" instead of that 1 I need {{students.id}} but unable to get

2. Controller function:

   $scope.gotoProfile = function (sid) {
       console.log($scope.purl);
       var rurl = $scope.purl+sid;
       $location.url(rurl);
   };

When I run this I am getting url

http://localhost/product/tcm_dev/utility/dashboard#/http://localhost/product/tcm_dev/utility/student/profile/1

like this.

Please help.
Thank You 
Prashant

Comment: gotoProfile(students.id) should work.

Comment: @Ved thanks ved.. One problem has been solved.. But still stuck with redirect url. it append that url instead redirect.. :(

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: $scope.gotoProfile = function (sid) { 
   console.log($scope.purl); 
   var rurl = $scope.purl+sid; 
   $location.url(rurl); 
};

Here I need url: http://localhost/product/tcm_dev/utility/student/profile/1

But on click it looks like 
http://localhost/product/tcm_dev/utility/dashboard#/http://localhost/product/tcm_dev/utility/student/profile/1

Comment: what you get : $scope.purl+sid

Comment: http://localhost/product/tcm_dev/utility/student/profile/3

This one which last id as a student id..

Comment: that is wrong. your location url should be= student/profile/1

Comment: But this rurl variable have the correct url which i need to redirect.. as I did console.log..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `<tr ng-repeat="students in studlist" ng-click="gotoProfile(student.id)">` to send student.id

and how about use `$window.location.href=(rurl);` instead of `$location.url(rurl);`

if you want to open a new page, use `$window.location.href=(rurl,'_blank');`